# Regarding shift operators

Tags: java

```
public class Shift{

    public static void shift1(){
        int i = 0;
        while(-1 << i != 0){
            i++
        }
    }

    public void shift2(){
        for(int i=-1;i!=0;i<<=1){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The first method goes to infinite loop where as second iterates 31 times to become 0;why does java only consider the lower order 5 bits of right operand while shifting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's what is specified in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19): "If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance."

A lot of hardware works that way as well.

Comment: `java only consider the lower order 5 bits of right operand while shifting`. I'm unable to understand what this means. Can please help.

Answer (score 2):

Shifting by 32 or more isn't done by Java both because it's a fairly useless operation on ints, and simply because that is how it is specified to work.

Answer (score 0):

The "lowest 5 bits" is not relevant.

-1 is represented as 32 "1" bits: `11111111111111111111111111111111`

Each `<< 1` operation chews up one of those bits until `i` is zero - that's what's controlling the number of iterations.

Comment: *32* '1' bits: `0xffffffff`.